# issue with connect to Cassandra by spark in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, docker, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have server with docker and create 3 Cassandra node , 2 worker spark node and one master spark node.
Now i want to connect to spark from my Laptop by java application.
my java code is :

```
public SparkTestPanel(String id, User user) {
    super(id);
    form = new Form("form");
    form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    this.add(form);
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true);
    conf.setAppName("Spark Test");
    conf.setMaster("spark://172.11.100.156:9050");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cassandra-0");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra"); 
    JavaSparkContext sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        CassandraTableScanJavaRDD<com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow> cassandraTable = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "test_table");

        List<com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow> collect = cassandraTable.collect();
        for(com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow cassandraRow : collect){
            Logger.getLogger(SparkTestPanel.class).error(cassandraRow.toString());
        }
    } finally {
        sc.stop();
    }

}
```

and I know that application connect to spark master because i see my app on web ui of spark but on line:

```
CassandraTableScanJavaRDD<com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow> cassandraTable = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "test_table");
```

I get below error:

```
2017-08-17 12:14:31,906 ERROR CassandraConnectorConf:72 - Unknown host 'cassandra-0'
java.net.UnknownHostException: cassandra-0: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
...
```

And other error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot build a cluster without contact points
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.checkNotEmpty(Cluster.java:119)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:112)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:178)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1335)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:131)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:159)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:32)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.syncAcquire(RefCountedCache.scala:69)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:57)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:79)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:122)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:330)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.tableFromCassandra(Schema.scala:350)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:50)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:62)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:62)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:137)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:62)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

And I go to server("172.11.100.156") and got to spark-master container ping cassandra-0 and see:

```
root@708d210056af:/# ping cassandra-0
PING cassandra-0 (21.1.0.21): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 21.1.0.21: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.554 ms
64 bytes from 21.1.0.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
64 bytes from 21.1.0.21: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
64 bytes from 21.1.0.21: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
```

what happened in my application that can got this error?
Can any one help?

Comment: Did you try ip address of cassandra-0 in 'spark.cassandra.connection.host'?

Comment: cassandra-0 should get resolved in master as well as worker nodes

Comment: yes,i try it's ip address that seen in to the docker.but when try server ip address("172.11.100.156") and spark.cassandra.connection.host=7005(port that i listen to 9042 of Cassandra-0 container) can connect  and no error seen.@addmeaning

Comment: cassandra-0 resolved in master and workers but my application that not in to the docker can not resolve it.@undefined_variable

Comment: Post your configuration for creating the cluster

Comment: check your etc/hosts file and try to add the ip address.

Comment: Cassandra or spark ?@TarunLalwani

Comment: which system?(server or my laptop)